# Select distinct from temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to select distinct values from my temporary table column into varchar variable in sql server.

i tried following but it doesnt work.

```
DECLARE @GuidPrimaryTableSpace NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @GuidPrimaryTableSpace = '';

SELECT DISTINCT
       @GuidPrimaryTableSpace = @GuidPrimaryTableSpace+DeleteGuidStatement+';'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
FROM ##Purge_GuidForeignKeyTablePurgeStatements;
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the XML approach for string concatenation:

```
SELECT @GuidPrimaryTableSpace =
           STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + DeleteGuidStatement
                  FROM ##Purge_GuidForeignKeyTablePurgeStatements
                  FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                        ), 1, 3, ''
                )
FROM ##Purge_GuidForeignKeyTablePurgeStatements;
```

You can use your method if you use a subquery:

```
DECLARE @GuidPrimaryTableSpace NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @GuidPrimaryTableSpace = '';

SELECT @GuidPrimaryTableSpace = @GuidPrimaryTableSpace + DeleteGuidStatement + ';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DeleteGuidStatement
      FROM ##Purge_GuidForeignKeyTablePurgeStatements
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon. It works fine but there is another issue here. it doesnt let me order by Id.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT DeleteGuidStatement
      FROM ##Purge_GuidForeignKeyTablePurgeStatements Order by ID throws an error as "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."